# Not able to execute exe file located at different server through powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exe, powershell-3.0

Exe File is located at shared folder on different server how to execute this.

Answer (score 0):

copy/move the file into your server first.

Comment: the exe file is located in shared folder .. i can access this folder through run.. however from powershell i want to exexcute that file.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this behavior is by design, and regarded as a safety feature.   There are several ways around it.   If you don't want to copy the file as suggested by techfang, you might use the following switches to launch PowerShell in a mode where it should do what you want:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File <server-file-path>
```

I have to say that a "security" feature this easy to bypass doesn't seem very secure, but I think the intent is simply to avoid unintentional execution of script that might do things you regret.   You may end up getting used to it, but the above is not something you should do lightly.